# UIImagePickerController doesn't call delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I've got a `UIImagePickerController` with sourceType set to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` and that allowsEditing.

It's delegate methods don't get called.

If sourceType is `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` or if I turn allowsEditing off then they are being called.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: I haven't had this issue before. Can you post your code so we can help investigate futher?

Comment: @BrianSachetta I was surprised myself, but just found the problem. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it's rare, but might help someone with a similar issue.

Make sure that in your project the push and pop method for UINavigationController aren't swizzled.

In my case it was setup to ignore other pushes/pops if another push/pop is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

are you connecting delegate to self?

```
yourpickercontroller.delegate = self
```

add this to viewDidLoad